# How to have an IF OR in android?

Tags: java, android

```
  if(word.equals(" ")){
  }
```

I have this IF statment, what i would like it to also do is the following..

```
 if(word.equals(" ") OR word.equals(".") ){
  }
```

I know the above code will not work, but im looking how to implement something like that? Anyone know how to do an if or, or do i have to use else if?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Android uses Java, and the boolean OR operator in Java (and in pretty much every single language with a C-inspired syntax) is `||`.

```
if (word.equals(" ") || word.equals("."))
```

Here is a [document describing the Java operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You may also want to [read it from the start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) since it covers the basics of Java.

There are [thousands of tutorials on Google explaining the basics of the Java language](http://www.google.ca/search?q=java%20tutorial) that you could also use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the reason the question was asked is that you must do this test BEFORE trying to do a  .parseDouble  on 'word' or else the app will crash